# ASP.NET Update Command and SQL Logic

Tags: mysql

I am attempting to use the update command on an ASP.NET website and my logic of SQL follows:

```
UPDATE (SELECT `Event Name`,`Date`,`Time`,`Location`,`Goal`,`ID` FROM Calendar)
```

but, MySQL returns an error:

> #1248 - Every derived table must have its own alias

Any ideas to fix this would be appreciated.  Also, I have seen this alternative to plain SQL commands:   http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.datagrid.updatecommand.aspx

All solutions would be helpful in structuring this ASP site (C#).  Please keep in mind I am new to this technology.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The update statement looks a bit weird. Shouldn't it something like this:

```
UPDATE Calendar 
SET [Event Name] = @Event, Date = @date, Time = @time, 
Location = @location, Goal = @goal
WHERE ID = @id
```

Watch the spaces in column names, you should surround them with square braces, i.e. `[Event name]`.

Comment: Would you happen to know how to use the UPDATE command in ASP.Net?

Comment: If by that you mean wether I know how to update a record in a database using ASP.NET, then yes. There are several ways of doing it, the above SQL statement can be executed with SQLCommand object. You may want to look at an ORM like Entity Framework, NHibernate or LINQ To SQL rather than handcrafting your UPDATE statements.

Comment: Thanks, but I should define this further.  I now figured out the update command but, the first column does not get updated and all other columns do:

Comment: UPDATE  Calendar SET `Event Name`=@`Event Name`,`Date`=@Date,`Time`=@Date,`Location`=@Location,`Goal`=@Goal WHERE `ID`=@ID

Comment: That worked.  Also, this did as well:  UPDATE  Calendar SET `Event_Name`=@Event_Name,`Date`=@Date,`Time`=@Date,`Location`=@Location,`Goal`=@Goal WHERE `ID`=@ID